# How to change path data with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change path data to none on mouseover. On mouse out, I want to change the value to something else.

What's wrong with my code?

This is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<button id="buttonjs">
    <svg width="10" height="10">
        <g fill-rule="evenodd">
            <path id="pathjs"  d="M0 5h7"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
    </button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("buttonjs").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
document.getElementById("buttonjs").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
        
        function mouseOver() {
          document.getElementById("pathjs").getAttribute('d, 0');
        }
        
        function mouseOut() {
          document.getElementById("pathjs").getAttribute('d, M0 5h7');
        }
```

Comment: I believe you need setAttribute not getAttribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.setAttribute('d', 'M0 5h7')`

```js
 
document.getElementById("buttonjs").onmouseover = function() {
  mouseOver()
};


document.getElementById("buttonjs").onmouseout = function() {
  mouseOut()
};
        
function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("pathjs").setAttribute('d', ' 0');
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("pathjs").setAttribute('d', 'M0 5h7');
}
```

```html
Button
<button id="buttonjs">
    <svg width="10" height="10">
        <g fill-rule="evenodd">
            <path id="pathjs"  d="M0 5h7"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</button>
```